Chrome devtool: some function calls present in callstack but not in performance tab

In line 25908 createRootImpl is called and in line 25931 createContainer is called and it is also obvious in callstack

However in performance tab, there is no way to see createContainer, createRootImpl call listenToAllSupportedEvents in line 25919 directly

How can this happen? is it a Chrome bug or something I never understand?
